# "The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call." problem

Tags: c++, x86, stack

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weird MSC 8.0 error: “The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call…”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142644/weird-msc-8-0-error-the-value-of-esp-was-not-properly-saved-across-a-function-c)

I have an OBJ file for which I don't have any soure code. I have used it in another project without any problems. Now I am trying to use it in another project. Here is the way I declare it:

```
extern "C" bool FileCompare(char* file1, char* file2);
```

I use it in a function like this:

```
void myFunction() {
    //some code
    FileCompare(file1, file2); // file1 and 2 are char arrays
}
```

Then in my main code I call myFunction:

```
int main() {
    ... some code
    myFunction()
}
```

When myFunction returns I get "The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call." in Visual Studio 2010 debugger. However, I know for a fact that FileCompares (the function in the obj file) does its job. When I comment it out everything works fine. I have used this OBJ file in the past without any problems. Considering I don't have the source of the obj file, is there anything I can do to try to "patch" this problem?

Thank you very much

More details: I suspect that the code uses CALL without RET (its written in assembly).

EDIT: I don't know if what I say makes sense the way things work, but since the function corrupts the esp is there anyway to save it and restore it after the function returns?

Comment: Was the obj file compiled with VS2010 too? With or without SP1?

Comment: Or: [The value of ESP was not saved properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104774/the-value-of-esp-was-not-saved-properly).

Comment: The OBJ file was written and compiled with masm

Comment: More details: I suspect that the code uses CALL without RET (its written in assembly).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by, "the code uses CALL without RET"?

Comment: Both platforms are identical (e.g. 32-bit x86)?

Comment: Incidentally, `extern "C" bool ...` is technically wrong, because there is no "bool" in C.

Answer (score 4):

This is either due to a bug in `FileCompare()` or mismatched calling conventions between the declaration and implementation of `myFunction()` and/or `FileCompare()`.

You might be able to fix the problem with an appropriate specifier (like maybe `__cdecl`) on the prototype for `FileCompare()`.  Or you might need to create an assembly language wrapper for the `FileCompare()` function that fixes things up (since you say that you no longer have the source for `FileCompare()`).

Figuring out exactly what's wrong without `FileCompare()` source might require stepping thorough the assembly in a debugger.

Comment: +1 for a good answer, but he says he "used it in another project without any problems"...  So I wonder what differs between the projects?

Comment: @Nemo: screwing up `ESP` doesn't always result in a visible problem - if `EBP` is used as the frame register, then locals will still be accessible, and `ESP` will often be restored when the caller is done because it's often restored by simply moving `EBP` into it. In other words, it's very dependent on the tools and exact circumstances as to whether it'll be noticed.

Answer (score 4):

I run into a similar problem once when I was compiling one project against old header file that differed from the latest by one missing virtual function.