# c# COM object & "The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call..."

Tags: c#, c++, com

I've got a COM object wtitten on c#, and i'm using it in a c++ dll.

In c++ the COM object is imported with `#import` derective

The problem is that when the call is made from a c++ dll to any function of the COM object i'm getting a runtime check error:

> Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved
>   across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a
>   function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer
>   declared with a different calling convention.

In the com object wrapper generated by c++ import directive, all functions are declared as `__stdcall`

Comment: possible duplicate of [The value of ESP was not saved properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104774/the-value-of-esp-was-not-saved-properly)

Comment: That's a very unusual problem with COM calls, the calling convention and argument types are all machine generated.  You'll need to do a better job describing your code, at least post snippets of the C# declaration and the C++ call.  The trivial explanation is that you are using an old version of the type library.

Comment: it looks like i'v found the solution:
i'v declated In/Out/MarshalAs attributes for all methods and parameters in c# COM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it looks like I have found the solution:
I have declated In/Out/MarshalAs attributes for all methods in the C# COM interface:

```
[Guid("EEB4C1AE-4DB2-4bdb-86D4-A429B27496A3")]
public interface IAXFarCards
{
    [DispId(1)]
    void InitDbConnection([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string connectionString);

    [DispId(2)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    int GetCardInfo(
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]             string card,
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VariantBool)]      bool   isTemplate,
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]               int    cashDeskId,
        [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VariantBool)] out bool   isActive,
        [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]          out int    discountNumber,
        [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I8)]          out Int64  amount,
        [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]    ref string ownerName,
        [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]      ref int    clientId
        );
```